# Where could I post an article about Electrum to get it reviewed?

Tags: electrum

I am writing a short, basic article about Electrum.

I am quite new to bitcoins, and was hoping I could get somebody to have a look at it, to check that I didn't write anything totally stupid (which is likely).

The article is meant to be a very basic guide on how to use Electrum, keeping everything very basic and simple. I want to give just enough hints in terms of theory, without getting too deep into it.

Where could I post it, in order to get it reviewed?

Comment: I assume that you mean to ask "where can I post it, in order to get it reviewed?". Is that correct?

Comment: Yep sorry... that's what I meant!

Comment: If anybody is interested: http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/simple_guide_bitcoins_using_electrum

Comment: That reads very nicely! Only one thing I've noticed: Once you've used Bitcoins capitalized, while you did not for most of the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try posting it to [/r/electrum](http://www.reddit.com/r/electrum), [/r/bitcoin](http://reddit.com/r/bitcoin), or [the Electrum section of BitcoinTalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=98.0).